# Save UISlider value after changing it's value

Tags: ios6

I have button on my NavigationController that popover other UITabBarViewController,
also in one of the tabs I have UISlider.
Problem is that when I change UISlider value and than close this popover, after I return to
this UISlider it doesn't save previous value.

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my quiestion in Stackoverflow.

[How to save a UISlider's Position (Or current value)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286406/how-to-save-a-uisliders-position-or-current-value)

But instead of sharedDefaults, I used standardUserDefaults method.